# windows update application

Tags: c#, .net, msdn, windows-update

I wrote here an application that uses the WUA COM interfaces (`IUpdateSearcher`, `IUpdate` etc.). I use this application to scan for available updates, download the updates and install them. Everything works OK until I get to download and install some update have some ui update dialog.

I get this update when I use `IUpdateSearcher.Search()`, I can successfully download it (using `IUpdateDownloader.Download()`) but when I install this update using `IUpdateInstaller2.Install()` I cannot get rid of the user interface.

My question is - how can I make this a silent installation?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, may I ask why are you writing such an application?

Comment: it's part of big system that control on many pc.. (one of the option is to control on the windows update of eche PC...)

Comment: find the solution use IUpdateInstaller2 instend IUpdateInstaller, there is "forcesielte" property...

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WUApiLib;
namespace MSHWindowsUpdateAgent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UpdatesAvailable();
            EnableUpdateServices();//enables everything windows need in order to make an update
            InstallUpdates(DownloadUpdates());
            Console.Read();
        }
        //this is my first try.. I can see the need for abstract classes here...
        //but at least it gives most people a good starting point.
        public static  void InstalledUpdates()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
            ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=1 AND IsHidden=0");
            //for the above search criteria refer to 
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
            //Check the remakrs section

            foreach (IUpdate x in SearchResults.Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Title);
            }
        }
        public static void UpdatesAvailable()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
            ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND IsPresent=0");
            //for the above search criteria refer to 
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
            //Check the remakrs section

            foreach (IUpdate x in SearchResults.Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Title);
            }
        }
        public static UpdateCollection DownloadUpdates()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher SearchUpdates = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            ISearchResult UpdateSearchResult = SearchUpdates.Search("IsInstalled=0 and IsPresent=0");
            UpdateCollection UpdateCollection = new UpdateCollection();
            //Accept Eula code for each update
            for (int i = 0; i < UpdateSearchResult.Updates.Count; i++)
            {
                IUpdate Updates = UpdateSearchResult.Updates[i];
                if (Updates.EulaAccepted == false)
                {
                    Updates.AcceptEula();
                }
                UpdateCollection.Add(Updates);
            }
            //Accept Eula ends here
            //if it is zero i am not sure if it will trow an exception -- I havent tested it.

                UpdateCollection DownloadCollection = new UpdateCollection();
                UpdateDownloader Downloader = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();

                for (int i = 0; i < UpdateCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    DownloadCollection.Add(UpdateCollection[i]);
                }

                Downloader.Updates = DownloadCollection;
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updates");
                IDownloadResult DownloadResult = Downloader.Download();
                UpdateCollection InstallCollection = new UpdateCollection();
                for (int i = 0; i < UpdateCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (DownloadCollection[i].IsDownloaded)
                    {
                        InstallCollection.Add(DownloadCollection[i]);
                    }
                }
                return InstallCollection;
        }
        public static void InstallUpdates(UpdateCollection DownloadedUpdates)
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            UpdateInstaller InstallAgent = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller() as UpdateInstaller;
            InstallAgent.Updates = DownloadedUpdates;

            //Starts a synchronous installation of the updates.
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386491(v=VS.85).aspx#methods
            IInstallationResult InstallResult = InstallAgent.Install();

        }
        public static void EnableUpdateServices()
        {
            IAutomaticUpdates updates = new AutomaticUpdates();
            if (!updates.ServiceEnabled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not all updates services where enabled. Enabling Now" + updates.ServiceEnabled);
                updates.EnableService();
                Console.WriteLine("Service enable success");
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jvelez has an excellent answer but it does not directly answer the actual question: "how can I make this a silent instaltion?"

confi - I would suggest the easiest way first:

```
static class Program
{
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.EnableVisualStyles();

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Visible = false;
form1.ShowInTaskbar = false;
Application.Run(form1);
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
}
}
```

Ensuring all the methods were working in the background by simply hiding your UI this would give you a means of making it silent.

@Justin Choponis - I have a need to do the same as confi. WSUS is not cutting it for many of my clients. Its impratical and bulky. If you had one Network to look after and were onsite all the time WSUS is then usefull other than that I find it very un-satisfactory.